# Using binary COPY to load jsonb[] column

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to upload a table with the pgx driver in Go.

I use the copy API and fail on `jsonb[]` column; it generates an error:

```
number of array dimensions (2065857372) exceeds the maximum allowed (6)
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps, if you share your table definition and a relevant part of the CSV file.

Comment: I upload with binary format, in CSV it works fine

Comment: I found related issue - https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was a bug in pgx driver, it not provide correct binary representation for jsonb[], it must sent upfront int32 with dimension and sizes, and then actual data.

Fix already merged in this PR - https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/pull/43

Answer (score 0):

For binary copy, you have to supply the internal PostgreSQL binary format of a `json[]`. You'd have to read the PostgreSQL source for that.

Don't use the binary format.